# MVC 3 @Html.DropDownListFor model binding fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, html.dropdownlistfor

I am using VS 2010 with MVC 3 and EF 5. I am using a common pattern for dropdown lists that works correctly in all but one instance and I cannot see why this one is failing to select the correct entry in the select list. The following are code snippets.

The select list is created as follows:

```
   public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetOutcomes()
    {
        CodesEntities dataContextCodes = new CodesEntities(ConnectionString);

        return new SelectList(dataContextCodes.CodeOutcome.
            Where(x => x.DisplayOrder > 0).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder), 
            "OutcomeCodeID", "Outcome");
    }
```

This returns the correct select list.

The view has the following code:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OutcomeCodeID,
                PerintalFormViewModels.GetOutcomes(), "Please select an item")
```

The model value `m.OutcomeCodeID` has a valid value (1) but no item is being selected.

The generated HTML is:

```
<select id="CodeID" name="OutcomeCodeID" data-val-required="Outcome is required" data-val-number="The field outcome must be a number." data-val="true">
<option value="">Please select an item</option>
<option value="1">Termination</option>
<option value="2">Loss</option>
<option value="3">Still</option>
<option value="4">Live</option>
</select>
```

I am in the hair tearing out, being driven nuts stage. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post generated HTML please?

Comment: Thanks, generated HTML added above.

Comment: What option are you expecting to be selected? The "Please select an item" option or the option that matches the current Id?

Comment: The one that matches the current ID (termination).

Comment: Can you provide model and controller action as well please?

Comment: Not easily - it's a complex model. The thing that is puzzling is that this example is identical to six others that I use elsewhere and all of which work. I have moved the 'snippet' to various places but still no joy.

Comment: How is your <select> id different from the name? The DropDownListFor should be generating the same value for id and name (OutcomeCodeID). Are you using a custom DropDownListFor helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetOutcomes(string selectedID)
{
    CodesEntities dataContextCodes = new CodesEntities(ConnectionString);


    return new SelectList(dataContextCodes.CodeOutcome.
        Where(x => x.DisplayOrder > 0).OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder), 
        "OutcomeCodeID", "Outcome"
        , selectedID); // add this parameter
}
```

Or this:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetOutcomes(string selectedID)
{
    CodesEntities dataContextCodes = new CodesEntities(ConnectionString);


    return        
      dataContextCodes.CodeOutCome
      .Where(x => x.DisplayOrder > 0)
      .OrderBy(x => x.DisplayOrder)
      .ToList()
      .Select(x => new SelectListItem 
      { 
          Value = x.OutcomeCodeID.ToString(),
          Text = x.Outcome.ToString(),
          Selected = x.OutcomeCodeID == selectedID
      });
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OutcomeCodeID,
            PerintalFormViewModels.GetOutcomes(Model.OutcomeCodeID), 
            "Please select an item")
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, that work's nicely. I'm still puzzled as to why the original didn't work but life's to sort to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the default selected value anywhere.

The particular constructor you are using for the SelectList is this one:

```
public SelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    string dataValueField,
    string dataTextField
)
```

Which does not set the default value. Either you use this one:

```
public SelectList(
    IEnumerable items,
    string dataValueField,
    string dataTextField,
    Object selectedValue
)
```

And specify the *selectedValue* or you manually set the SelectedListItem's Selected property to true on the item you want selected (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem(v=vs.108).aspx).

It's a shameless plug but still I think it's a good resource: http://blinkingcaret.wordpress.com/2012/08/11/using-html-dropdownlistfor/

Comment: Thanks Rui for the above tips